# How is "he do" possible grammatically?

Tags: grammar

> And if he **do not** these three unto her, then shall she go out for
>   nothing, without money. [Source](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0221.htm)

Another instance:

> Now **he don't** talk too much, talk too much. [Source](https://genius.com/Ady-suleiman-out-of-luck-lyrics)

Please explain how is it possible grammatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example appears to be poetry written in a specialized dialect. Either one of these situations (both *poetry* and *dialect*) will use language that does not follow the standard rules of grammar. It will be more helpful to beginning students of English to concentrate on more mainstream material if they want to analyze the structure of sentences.

Going back to your first example, from the Bible: the translation there is also not standard in today's English. The verb "do [not]" used in that passage is in the subjunctive form. If we were to use that verb form today we would probably add another word, "should", in an "if" clause to make it clear that we are talking about a conditional, counter-factual situation, and we would then write it as: "If he ***should* not do** these three ..."

But both of your examples are text that might confuse advanced students or even native speakers. If you don't worry about the structure of the sentences, the meaning of both of those examples seems pretty understandable, so don't worry if passages from poetic or archaic sources conflict with what you are learning about standard, modern English.

Answer (score 0):

The first example sounds perhaps archaic, definitely not current common usage. Perhaps someone else can shed more light.
The second example, I'm pretty sure, is simply colloquial -- technically, not correct English, but in actual common use.

Comment: Biblical text, archaic speech. "smiteth", "dieth", "unto", aren't in current usage.